# Can I yield from an instance method

Tags: python, python-itertools

Is it okay to use the yield statement in an instance method of a class?  For example,

```
# Similar to itertools.islice
class Nth(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.i = 0
        self.nout = 0

    def itervalues(self, x):
        for xi in x:
            self.i += 1
            if self.i == self.n:
                self.i = 0
                self.nout += 1
                yield self.nout, xi
```

Python doesn't complain about this, and simple cases seem to work.  However, I've only seen examples with yield from regular functions.

I start having problems when I try to use it with itertools functions.  For example, suppose I have two large data streams X and Y that are stored across multiple files, and I want to compute their sum and difference with only one loop through the data.  I could use `itertools.tee` and `itertools.izip` like in the following diagram

[image: data flow]

In code it would be something like this (sorry, it's long)

```
from itertools import izip_longest, izip, tee
import random

def add(x,y):
    for xi,yi in izip(x,y):
        yield xi + yi

def sub(x,y):
    for xi,yi in izip(x,y):
        yield xi - yi

class NthSumDiff(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.nthsum = Nth(n)
        self.nthdiff = Nth(n)

    def itervalues(self, x, y):
        xadd, xsub = tee(x)
        yadd, ysub = tee(y)
        gen_sum = self.nthsum.itervalues(add(xadd, yadd))
        gen_diff = self.nthdiff.itervalues(sub(xsub, ysub))
        # Have to use izip_longest here, but why?
        #for (i,nthsum), (j,nthdiff) in izip_longest(gen_sum, gen_diff):
        for (i,nthsum), (j,nthdiff) in izip(gen_sum, gen_diff):
            assert i==j, "sum row %d != diff row %d" % (i,j)
            yield nthsum, nthdiff

nskip = 12
ns = Nth(nskip)
nd = Nth(nskip)
nsd = NthSumDiff(nskip)
nfiles = 10
for i in range(nfiles):
    # Generate some data.
    # If the block length is a multiple of nskip there's no problem.
    #n = random.randint(5000, 10000) * nskip
    n = random.randint(50000, 100000)
    print 'file %d n=%d' % (i, n)
    x = range(n)
    y = range(100,n+100)
    # Independent processing is no problem but requires two loops.
    for i, nthsum in ns.itervalues(add(x,y)):
        pass
    for j, nthdiff in nd.itervalues(sub(x,y)):
        pass
    assert i==j
    # Trying to do both with one loops causes problems.
    for nthsum, nthdiff in nsd.itervalues(x,y):
        # If izip_longest is necessary, why don't I ever get a fillvalue?
        assert nthsum is not None
        assert nthdiff is not None
    # After each block of data the two iterators should have the same state.
    assert nsd.nthsum.nout == nsd.nthdiff.nout, \
           "sum nout %d != diff nout %d" % (nsd.nthsum.nout, nsd.nthdiff.nout)
```

But this fails unless I swap `itertools.izip` out for `itertools.izip_longest` even though the iterators have the same length.  It's the last `assert` that gets hit, with output like

```
file 0 n=58581
file 1 n=87978
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 71, in <module>
    "sum nout %d != diff nout %d" % (nsd.nthsum.nout, nsd.nthdiff.nout)
AssertionError: sum nout 12213 != diff nout 12212
```

**Edit**: I guess it's not obvious from the example I wrote, but the input data X and Y are only available in blocks (in my real problem they're chunked in files).  This is important because I need to maintain state between blocks.  In the toy example above, this means `Nth` needs to yield the equivalent of

```
>>> x1 = range(0,10)
>>> x2 = range(10,20)
>>> (x1 + x2)[::3]
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```

NOT the equivalent of

```
>>> x1[::3] + x2[::3]
[0, 3, 6, 9, 10, 13, 16, 19]
```

I could use `itertools.chain` to join the blocks ahead of time and then make one call to `Nth.itervalues`, but I'd like to understand what's wrong with maintaining state in the `Nth` class between calls (my real app is image processing involving more saved state, not simple Nth/add/subtract).

I don't understand how my `Nth` instances end up in different states when their lengths are the same.  For example, if I give `izip` two strings of equal length

```
>>> [''.join(x) for x in izip('ABCD','abcd')]
['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc', 'Dd']
```

I get a result of the same length; how come my `Nth.itervalues` generators seem to be getting unequal numbers of `next()` calls even though each one yields the same number of results?

Comment: To answer the title question: Yes, `yield`ing from instance methods is fine. It's actually the simplest most Pythonic way to implement `__iter__` for a custom `Iterable` type.

Comment: Couldn't you replace `class Nth` with `def Nth(x, n): return enumerate(x[::n])` ? Oh, or do you need the slicing of `x` to be an iterator, too, for performance reasons?

Comment: `def Nth(x, n): return enumerate(xi for i, xi in enumerate(x) if i % n == 0)`

Comment: Also, why not use Nth() on x and y from the start and then do your add and sub calls on the entire result?

Comment: @Harvey: [`itertools.islice` is a thing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice); don't need to reinvent the wheel with custom generator expressions. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger: he seemed to have a reason for not using itertools. I was just accommodating. :)

Comment: @Harvey: But the OP is actually using `izip`/`izip_longest`! It's right there! Why make your life harder? (To be clear not actually upset here, just spouting off for fun).

Comment: @ShadowRanger @Harvey I'm aware of islice and mentioned it in first line of the example.  My actual problem is more complicated; this was just the simplest example I could muster that demonstrates the synchronization issue with `tee`/`izip`.  A class like `Nth` seems like the most natural way to maintain state when iterating over multiple chunks of data.

Comment: I guess I could `itertools.chain` the input blocks first to avoid multiple calls to `Nth.itervalues`.  Still, I'd like to understand what the problem is with the algorithm as implemented.

Comment: So, is your intent to do this `(x1 + x2)[::3]` like you have above or this `(x1 + x2)[3-1::3]` like you coded Nth to do? One results in `[0,3,6,9,...]` while you coded the other to be `[2,5,8,11,...]`. So is it every Nth value starting with the first value or every Nth value starting with the Nth value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condensing the discussion, there's nothing wrong with using `yield` in an instance method *per se*.  You get into trouble with `izip` if the instance state changes after the last `yield` because `izip` stops calling `next()` on its arguments once any of them stops yielding results.  A clearer example might be

```
from itertools import izip

class Three(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = 'init'

    def run(self):
        self.status = 'running'
        yield 1
        yield 2
        yield 3
        self.status = 'done'
        raise StopIteration()

it = Three()
for x in it.run():
    assert it.status == 'running'
assert it.status == 'done'

it1, it2 = Three(), Three()
for x, y in izip(it1.run(), it2.run()):
    pass
assert it1.status == 'done'
assert it2.status == 'done', "Expected status=done, got status=%s." % it2.status
```

which hits the last assertion,

```
AssertionError: Expected status=done, got status=running.
```

In the original question, the `Nth` class can consume input data after its last `yield`, so the sum and difference streams can get out of sync with `izip`.  Using `izip_longest` would work since it will try to exhaust each iterator.  A clearer solution might be to refactor to avoid changing state after the last yield.

Answer (score 2):

[Gist repo with revisions](https://gist.github.com/sr105/694deeca9acb55618434)  | 
 [Quick link to solution](https://gist.github.com/sr105/694deeca9acb55618434/f42f2fbd2fe725617c480f0c3f00bf4b2e66e05c#file-nth-py-L12)

## Quick answer

You never reset `self.i` and `self.nout` in `class Nth`. Also, you should have used something like this:

```
# Similar to itertools.islice
class Nth(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def itervalues(self, x):
        for a,b in enumerate(islice(x, self.n - 1, None, self.n)):
            self.nout = a
            yield a,b
```

but since you don't even need `nout`, you should use this:

```
def Nth(iterable, step):
    return enumerate(itertools.islice(iterable, step - 1, None, step))
```

## Long answer

Your code had an off-by-one smell that led me to this line in NthSumDiff.itervalues():

```
for (i,nthsum), (j,nthdiff) in izip(gen_sum, gen_diff):
```

If you swap `gen_sum` and `gen_diff`, you'll see that `gen_diff` will always be the one with `nout` greater by one. This is because `izip()` pulls from `gen_sum` before pulling from `gen_diff`. `gen_sum` raises a StopIteration exception before `gen_diff` is even tried in the last iteration.

For example, say you pick N samples where N % step == 7. At the end of each iteration, `self.i` for the Nth instances should equal 0. But on the very last iteration, `self.i` in `gen_sum` will increment up to 7 and then there will be no more elements in `x`. It will raise StopIteration. `gen_diff` is still sitting at `self.i` equal to 0, though.

If you add `self.i = 0` and `self.nout = 0` to the beginning of Nth.itervalues(), the problem goes away.

## Lesson

You only had this problem because your code is too complicated and not Pythonic. If you find yourself using lots of counters and indexes in loops, that's a good sign (in Python) to take a step back and see if you can simplify your code. I have a long history of C programming, and consequently, I still catch myself doing the same thing from time to time in Python.

## Simpler implementation

*Putting my money where my mouth is...*

```
from itertools import izip, islice
import random

def sumdiff(x,y,step):
    # filter for the Nth values of x and y now
    x = islice(x, step-1, None, step)
    y = islice(y, step-1, None, step)
    return ((xi + yi, xi - yi) for xi, yi in izip(x,y))

nskip = 12
nfiles = 10
for i in range(nfiles):
    # Generate some data.
    n = random.randint(50000, 100000)
    print 'file %d n=%d' % (i, n)
    x = range(n)
    y = range(100,n+100)
    for nthsum, nthdiff in sumdiff(x,y,nskip):
        assert nthsum is not None
        assert nthdiff is not None
    assert len(list(sumdiff(x,y,nskip))) == n/nskip
```

## More explanation of the problem

In response to Brian's comment:

> This doesn't do the same thing. Not resetting i and nout is
>   intentional. I've basically got a continuous data stream X that's
>   split across several files. Slicing the blocks gives a different
>   result than slicing the concatenated stream (I commented earlier about
>   possibly using itertools.chain). Also my actual program is more
>   complicated than mere slicing; it's just a working example. I don't
>   understand the explanation about the order of StopIteration. If
>   izip('ABCD','abcd') --> Aa Bb Cc Dd then it seems like equal-length
>   generators should get an equal number of next calls, no? – Brian
>   Hawkins 6 hours ago

Your problem was so long that I missed the part about the stream coming from multiple files. Let's just look at the code itself. First, we need to be really clear about how `itervalues(x)` actually works.

```
# Similar to itertools.islice
class Nth(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.i = 0
        self.nout = 0

    def itervalues(self, x):
        for xi in x:
            # We increment self.i by self.n on every next()
            # call to this generator method unless the
            # number of objects remaining in x is less than
            # self.n. In that case, we increment by that amount
            # before the for loop exits normally.
            self.i += 1
            if self.i == self.n:
                self.i = 0
                self.nout += 1
                # We're yielding, so we're a generator
                yield self.nout, xi
        # Python helpfully raises StopIteration to fulfill the 
        # contract of an iterable. That's how for loops and
        # others know when to stop.
```

In `itervalues(x)` above, for every `next()` call, it internally increments `self.i` by `self.n` and then yields OR it increments `self.i` by the number of objects remaining in `x` and then exits the for loop and then exits the generator (itervalues() is a generator because it yields). When the itervalues() generator exits, Python raises a StopIteration exception.

So, for every instance of `class Nth` initialized with N, the value of `self.i` after exhausting all elements in `itervalues(X)` will be:

```
self.i = value_of_self_i_before_itervalues(X) + len(X) % N
```

Now when you iterate over `izip(Nth_1, Nth_2)`, it will do something like this:

```
def izip(A, B):
    try:
        while True:
            a = A.next()
            b = B.next()
            yield a,b
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

So, imagine `N=10` and `len(X)=13`. On the very last `next()` call to `izip()`,
both A and B have `self.i==0` as their state. `A.next()` is called, increments `self.i += 3`, runs out of elements in X, exits the for loop, returns, and then Python raises `StopIteration`. Now, inside `izip()` we go directly to the exception block skipping `B.next()` entirely. So, `A.i==3` and `B.i==0` at the end.

## Second try at simplification (with correct requirements)

Here's another simplified version that treats all file data as one continuous stream. It uses chained, small, re-usable generators. I would highly, highly recommend watching this [PyCon '14 talk about generators by David Beazley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-qadlG7tWo). Guessing from your problem description, it should be 100% applicable.

```
from itertools import izip, islice
import random

def sumdiff(data):
    return ((x + y, x - y) for x, y in data)

def combined_file_data(files):
    for i,n in files:
        # Generate some data.
        x = range(n)
        y = range(100,n+100)
        for data in izip(x,y):
            yield data

def filelist(nfiles):
    for i in range(nfiles):
        # Generate some data.
        n = random.randint(50000, 100000)
        print 'file %d n=%d' % (i, n)
        yield i, n

def Nth(iterable, step):
    return islice(iterable, step-1, None, step)

nskip = 12
nfiles = 10
filedata = combined_file_data(filelist(nfiles))
nth_data = Nth(filedata, nskip)
for nthsum, nthdiff in sumdiff(nth_data):
    assert nthsum is not None
    assert nthdiff is not None
```

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing.  Not resetting `i` and `nout` is intentional.  I've basically got a continuous data stream X that's split across several files.  Slicing the blocks gives a different result than slicing the concatenated stream (I commented earlier about possibly using `itertools.chain`).  Also my actual program is more complicated than mere slicing; it's just a working example.  I don't understand the explanation about the order of `StopIteration`.  If `izip('ABCD','abcd')` --> Aa Bb Cc Dd then it seems like equal-length generators should get an equal number of `next` calls, no?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. Refactoring Nth/add/sub is not useful to me since the processing in my real app is more complex, and I'd already mentioned `itertools.chain`ing the input data.  The discussion of `izip` was what I found most helpful.